# Почему все-таки НА Кавказе?

Tags: предлоги

Насколько я помню, тут уже не раз обсуждался вопрос, почему в одних случаях для обозначения местонахождения мы говорим "на", а в других "в" (хотя в случае с Украиной этот вопрос до сих пор спорный, как в популярной шутке: "Есть разница между находиться НА земле или В земле"). И выяснили, что предлог "на" употребляется, когда речь идет об острове: на Кубе, на Сахалине. Хотя тут опять же спорно, когда речь заходит о полуостровах: в Крыму, но на Ямале.
Но все-таки логика какая-то прослеживается. При это совершенно не понятна логика употребления предлога "на" в случае с Кавказом. Это не полуостров и не остров. Если предположить, что это горная страна, то мы благополучно говорим "он побывал В Тибете". А что же такого особенного в Кавказе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"..Мне представляется совсем простая штука.."
Географические названия являются частным случаем имён собственных. И для них, как и для имён собственных, предлоги "в" и "на" имеют разное значение (ср. "в Волге" и "на Волге"). А дальше - какое значение реже используется с данным названием, то и выбывает.

Answer (score 0):

А также мы благополучно говорим "в Альпах", "в Карпатах", "в Гималаях". Но "на Урале". Допустимо и "на Тибете".

Думаю, что ответ может дать только лингвист, историк языка. А остальные должны просто принимать, что вот так говорят, а так не говорят.

Answer (score 0):

На выбор предлогов В и НА  влияют разные факторы: пространственное значение предлогов, традиция употребления, удобство произношения.

Предлог НА употребляется относительно территории: на Кавказе - на территории Кавказа. Предлог В определяет направленность внутрь предмета: В России, в Грузии, в Смоленске, но на Смоленщине.

При наличии вариантов территория противопоставляется организованной структуре - городу, стране (на Тибете - в Тибете).

Comment: >> Предлог НА употребляется относительно территории: на Кавказе - на территории Кавказа. Предлог В определяет направленность внутрь предмета: В России, в Грузии

Ни о чем. Был в России, был на Кавказе, в Альпах... Где территория, где нутро? И главное – почему?

Comment: Чтобы совсем понятно было: осуществляется выбор - в горной стране или на территории горной страны.

Comment: Кавказ – горная страна, Альпы – нет? Или наоборот?

Кавказ – территория, Альпы – нет?

Всё это в лучшем случае объяснения задним числом. В худшем – вообще не объяснения, ни о чем.

Comment: Объяснение любого факта делается задним числом, Вы об это не догадывались? Про влияние нескольких факторов тоже не дослышали?

Comment: >> Объяснение любого факта делается задним числом

Все равно что сказать: "Решить задачу – значит подогнать под ответ". Блестяще.

Comment: А Вы отличаете "решить задачу" от "объяснить решение"?

Comment: Практически нет. Я нахожу решение, а после того как нашел, ничего не стоит объяснить его. Пройти по тому же пути ещё раз – трудно ли?

Comment: Кавказ - "регион, примыкающий к Кавказскому хребту". И **границ**, "внутри" которых можно находиться, не имеет. Зато - имеет "центр", вокруг которого он сформирован. Аналогично с Уралом.  
Ямал - тоже "регион" без "границ". "Центром", по видимому, следует считать оконечность полуострова. А, вот, границы Крыма очерчены весьма чётко.. 
С другой стороны, Европа и Азия "границ" не имеют, а они - "в". А острова (строго "на") - ограничены весьма зримо..

Comment: Альпийского  хребта  нет, Тибетского  тоже  нет.  А   Гималайский  -  есть?

Comment: Гималаи имеют не только "центр", но и "границы" (достаточно резкий переход от "молодых" гор к равнинам или плато). Применимы оба предлога, "исторически" выбрали "в".